# Materialize css modal not showing

Tags: materialize

I've got a following code:

```
<?php if(UserModel::getInstance()->isLoggedIn()) { ?>
    <a class="modal-trigger waves-effect waves-light red btn right" href="#modalNewTopic">+ Add New Topic</a>

<?php } ?>

<?php if(UserModel::getInstance()->isLoggedIn()) { ?>
    <div id="modalNewTopic" data-ignore="true" class="modal">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <h4>Add New Topic</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            asdf
        </div>
    </div>
```

When I click on a button nothing is showed up. No errors were triggered in javascript console. What could be the problem?

Comment: You not close your php code properly in modal div section. Make it close and may be it can resolve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialise the modal plugin before you can use it. Add this to your JS file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.modal').modal();
});
```